# How can I add custom option to order on <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> Event

Tags: magento-1.9

When someone placed an order, I need to add a custom option with ordered item. The custom option already created for the product.

\Diamonds\etc\config.xml

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>    
            <observers>                
                <ikantam_diamonds_observer>                    
                    <type>singleton</type>                        
                    <class>Ikantam_Diamonds_Model_Observer</class>                        
                    <method>updateRingSize</method>                  
                </ikantam_diamonds_observer>                
            </observers>            
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

\Diamonds\Model\Observer.php

```
public function updateRingSize($observer) {
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $qiId = $item->getQuoteItemId();

            $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($qiId);

            /* **This is ideal code. you can replace this code**
            $optionCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addItemFilter($quoteItem)
                    ->addFilter('code', 'ring_size');
            foreach ($optionCollection as $oo) {
                $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
                $productOptions['additional_options'] = $oo->getValue();
                echo '<pre>';print_r($productOptions);exit;
                $item->setProductOptions($productOptions);
                $item->save();*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(If you suggest some code with add custom option after order success then it will great)

Comment: I hope this will help you [open link from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687630/howto-update-order-items-custom-option-in-magento)

Comment: I checked this. nothing works with this.